# Unable to get dynamically generated html control in one php page to next page

Tags: php, file-upload

```
//photoform.php

<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" name="phsub" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
session_start();
$op=$_POST["opcnt"];

if ($op!="Select")
{
    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<legend> Open Category </legend>";

    for ($i=1;$i<=$op;$i++)
{
    echo "<input name='ofile$i' id='ofile$i' type='file'/>";
    echo"<br>";
}
    echo "</fieldset>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php 
    $empty = $post = array(); 
    foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue) { 
        if(empty($varvalue)) { 
            $empty[$varname] = $varvalue; 
        } 
        else { 
            $post[$varname] = $varvalue; 
        } 
    } 
    print "<pre>"; 
    if (empty($empty)) { 
        print "None of the POSTed values are empty, posted:\n"; 
        var_dump($post); 
    } 
    else { 
        print "We have " . count($empty) . " empty values\n"; 
        print "Posted:\n"; 
        var_dump($post); 
        print "Empty:\n"; 
        var_dump($empty); 
        exit; 
    }
?>
```

Question : When I am listing all $post values, I am only getting the "submit" button which is static. I can see all generated file upload controls based on the condition. But unable to get the control in upload.php file. Can you please suggest if there is anything wrong in the code. I am new to PHP. Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Thanks - Abhik Banerjee

Comment: $op=$_POST["opcnt"]; so opcnt must be a number to show the elements - where is the form that takes you to this page?

Comment: what is $post? do you mean var_dump($_POST);??

Comment: opcnt must be a numeric value coming from previous page and I am getting that properly into photoform.php page. I am trying to print var_dump($_POST) in upload.php page.

Comment: try for ($i=1;$i<=intval($op);$i++) and dump the $_POST and $op as a check

Answer (score 0):

In `photoform.php` output the `$_POST` variable to confirm that `$_POST['opcnt']` is not `select`.

Also, if you can, add the actual output html from `photoform.php` as it is likely to missing fields and/or names of fields.

Also,

```
//upload.php

<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

To access form `POST` variables use `$_POST`.

// Update

As your `form` is submitting `input` with type as `file`, these are considered as a special case.  The values will be mapped to the `$_FILES` variable.

See the php docs [on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for more clarification.

Comment: Yes. I did the same. I didn't post the entire code from upload.php file. Here is the full code 
<?php

$empty = $post = array();
foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue) {
    if (empty($varvalue)) {
        $empty[$varname] = $varvalue;
    } else {
        $post[$varname] = $varvalue;
    }
}

print "<pre>";
if (empty($empty)) {
    print "None of the POSTed values are empty, posted:\n";
    var_dump($post);
} else {
    print "We have " . count($empty) . " empty values\n";
    print "Posted:\n"; var_dump($post);
    print "Empty:\n";  var_dump($empty);
    exit;
}

Comment: @AbhikBanerjee That is quite unreadable - Edit your question with this information.

Comment: @AbhikBanerjee I have added the code from your comment to your question.

Comment: I have also used
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>

But it's only showing the static submit button. Nothing else is there in the array of output.

Comment: @AbhikBanerjee Look at the output for `photoform.php` it must be missing form elements.

Comment: Here is the output of the generated html form
"<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" name="phsub" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateform2();">

<fieldset><legend> Open Category </legend><input name='ofile1' id='ofile1' type='file'/><br><input name='ofile1' id='ofile1' type='file'/><br></fieldset><br>
<input type="hidden" name="fpaths">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>"

Comment: @AbhikBanerjee `file` types are stored in `$_FILES`. Also, they have no values, so some browsers may not post them back. Add a value attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to find the file control by using $_FILES. But control can't be located via $_POST

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file details from 
     $_FILES